# Imprimir string en bucle con todos los números de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una lista con números y quiero imprimirlos junto a una string en bucle hasta que llegue al ultimo numero de la lista.

Con el siguiente código no me ha funcionado ya que me imprime todos los numeros juntos.

```
n = 5
list = list(range(0, n)) 
print (list)
print ("QPI{}SYN".format(list))
```

> QPI[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]SYN

Lo que yo querría es algo así:

> QPI0SYN QPI1SYN QPI2SYN...

Alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: Entonces en vez de un único `print()` lo más fácil ya que estás aprendiendo es que uses un bucle para recorrer la lista de números. Por cierto, usar `list` como nombre de variable no es muy buena idea, puesto que es una palabra reservada!

Comment: Te suguiero probar el formateo usando f-string. Queda más compacto `print (f"QPI{list}SYN")` y se entiende mejor cual será el resultado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo he conseguido resolver gracias a la aportación de Benito:

```
n = 5
lista = list(range(0, n)) 
print (lista)

for x in lista:
    seq2 = ("QPI{}SYN".format(x))
    print (seq2,end="")

QPI0SYNQPI1SYNQPI2SYNQPI3SYNQPI4SYN
```

Comment: Excelente! Y las variables correctamente renombradas! Solo un comentario más, no tengas miedo de escribir nombres de variables más largos y sobre todo, *representativos*. Por ejemplo en vez de `n`, yo habría usado `limit`, en vez de `lista` podrías usar `numbers`. Por lo general es mejor tener variables cuyo nombre te haga ver de un vistazo qué son puesto que si dentro de tres meses vuelves a ver el código, no necesitarás buscar dónde declaraste cada variable para saber *qué* es. De todos modos, excelente trabajo! :)

Answer (score 1):

Me gustaría añadir esta respuesta simplemente para darte otra opción y de paso que veas algo un poco más "avanzado" por si en algún momento te apetece un desafío un poco mayor y jugar un poco con Python y los [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp), ya que son realmente **muy** usados y potentes a la hora de trabajar con listas.

Como verás, el código se queda realmente pequeño (pero *entendible*), mientras que el resultado es exactamente el mismo:

```py
limit = 5
numbers = list(range(0, limit))
print(*["QPI{}SYN".format(number) for number in numbers])
```

Te explicaré un poco lo que hace eso dentro del `print()`, aunque empezaremos ignorando el asterisco:

- `[]`: Una lista de objetos es lo primero que necesitamos aquí, pues los *list comprehension* necesitan trabajar con listas tal como su nombre indica. Fíjate bien, que ***todo*** el código siguiente estará ***dentro*** de dicha lista!
- `QPI{}SYN".format()`: El literal que queremos que imprima **para cada valor** seleccionado de nuestra lista. Obviamente a `format()` se le pasa la variable `number`!
- `for number in numbers`: Un bucle dentro de una lista?? Efectivamente! Es un bucle `for` normal de python, simplemente está metido dentro de la propia lista y nos permite usar la variable `number` en el literal que especificamos antes del bucle!
- `*`: Por último, le he añadido un asterisco al principio, en python el [`*`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) es el operador para *desempaquetar* una lista, sin él, el resultado impreso por este código sería: `['QPI0SYN', 'QPI1SYN', 'QPI2SYN', 'QPI3SYN', 'QPI4SYN']`, pero con el asterisco "*eliminamos*" la lista, obteniendo `QPI0SYN QPI1SYN QPI2SYN QPI3SYN QPI4SYN`.

---

Este es un uso básico de los *list comprehension* de python, pero son mucho más poderosos de lo que aquí se ve, puesto que incluso nos permiten añadir condicionales (Los cuales se añadirían a continuación del `for number in numbers` directamente).

Comment: @andyio Creo que tendrás que esperar unas horas antes de poder marcar tu respuesta como aceptada. He añadido esta no para que la aceptes, si no para mostrar una manera más avanzada de hacer lo mismo y que si te apetece, pruebes a usarlo en otra ocasión. Por favor, acepta tu propia respuesta en cuanto el sistema te deje, porque las preguntas sin respuesta aceptada molestan a *Comunidad♦*, que se pasará el resto de su vida editándola para que la veas y aceptes una respuesta!